# Phonological terminology: what to call the /h/ → /p/ shift?

Tags: phonology, compounds, phonotactics

Japanese has various kinds of [sandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi#Japanese) or [連音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E9%9F%B3) (*ren'on*), of which [sequential voicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) or [連濁](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A3%E6%BF%81) (*rendaku*) is probably one of the best known.

There's also [gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) or [長子音化](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E5%AD%90%E9%9F%B3) (*chōshiinka*), where we get things like 学校 (*ga**kk**ō*) from 学 (*ga**k**u*) + 校 (***k**ō*).

Gemination with the //h// kana (outside of a few borrowings, like バッハ [*Ba**hh**a*, "Bach"]) generally also causes the //h// (or //ɸ//) to shift to //p// instead.  Things like 開けっ放し (*ake**pp**anashi*) from 開け (*ake*) + 放し (***h**anashi*).

I just can't seem to find what this particular sound shift is called.

Does anyone here know the name for this //h// → //p// shift?  Ideally in both English and Japanese?

Comment: Simply 半濁音化? 開けっ放し is a case of 促音化 but 半濁音化 can happen without 促音化 as in 全般.

Comment: That's probably it.  Let's see if anyone else chimes in. :)

Comment: And how do you say 半濁音化 in English? :)

Comment: /h/ (or /f/, /θ/, /s/, /x/...) → /ɸ/ could be called *bilabialization* ([両唇音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/両唇音)化 ?). /ɸ/ → /p/ could be called *defricativization* or *plosivization* ([破裂音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/破裂音)化 ?). I think that combined process could be called *bilabialization-plosivization* (両唇破裂音化 ?) (/p/ is [無声両唇破裂音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/無声両唇破裂音)).

Comment: @Arfrever -- _"And how do you say 半濁音化 in English? :)"_ Well, informally, I'd probably just say _"the //h// to //p// shift"_, but that is unlikely to be the "official" term for this.  

Comment: I wouldn't expect a useful term for this to be language-specific. I think this question is better suited for [linguistics.se].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I'm inquiring about the specifically Japanese and English names for a specific phenomenon in Japanese where はひふへほ becomes ぱぴぷぺぽ in compounds, often alongside the specific Japanese phonological process known as 促音 / 長子音化.  I don't think the broader [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) would be the correct forum for this question. 

Comment: Isn't it just the same rule that causes voicing for other voice-able consonants, just that there's also a "half-voiced" option for that column (never mind that linguists wouldn't pair h with p/b in the first place, although they would pair p and b)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, it sounds like you're talking about _rendaku_, such as when _hon_ becomes _bon_ in 三本. I'm talking instead about ... _whatever this phenomenon is called_, such as when _hon_ becomes _pon_ in 一本.

Comment: Right, I forgot the name. What I'm getting at is, I'm not really convinced that it's a *separate* phenomenon.

Comment: @Arfrever - Or could it be just *plosivization* of /φ/ preceding a later shift from /φ/ to /h/ (and its extrapolation to /h/ by modern speakers)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Note that at least origins of these phenomena are different. *Rendaku* is thought to originate in pre-Old Japanese from reduction of particles with nasal consonant (*nə*, *ni*). Remember that phonemically voiced consonants *b*, *d*, *z*, *g* were prenasalized until at least 17th century. Already in time of Old Japanese, *rendaku* was extended by analogy to cases originally without any such particles.

Comment: Re: prenasalization, that's still kind of a feature of some dialects - I recall talking to kids in Iwate prefecture, who pronounced 度【たび】 as たんび instead, with a distinct ん sound.